# ScrollView scrollTo doesn't work

Tags: android, scrollview

Same issue as [ScrollView .scrollTo not working? Saving ScrollView position on rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263259/scrollview-scrollto-not-working-saving-scrollview-position-on-rotation)

I dynamically add items to scrollView in onCreate. I try the following after all items were added:

```
    // no effect
    ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);

    // no effect
    ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);
    mainScroll.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);
            mainScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } 
    });

    // works like a charm
    ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);
    mainScroll.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);
            mainScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } 
    }, 30);
```

I conclude that there is some event like 'DOM-ready'? Are there any callbacks?

Comment: My best guess is that because the `ScrollView` hasn't been layed out or measured yet right after inflating it, the first approach doesn't work. By Adding a delay, you're giving the view hierarchy enough time to initialise. I would try attaching a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the `ScrollView`'s `ViewTreeObserver` to get notified of when the view is 'ready to scroll'.

Answer (score 20):

You don't need to extend the ScrollView and create your own as per the answer provided by [David Daudelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276216/david-daudelin) for the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753603/using-smoothscrollby-method-in-android-scrollview-class?rq=1).

Get the `ViewTreeObserver` of the `ScrollView` and add an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the `ViewTreeObserver`. Then call the `ScrollView.scrollTo(x,y)` method from the `onGlobalLayout()` method of the `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. Code:

```
 ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);

 ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
 vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
           mainScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me, replace `scrollView.scrollTo()` to

```
     scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, ScrollViewYPosition);//0 is x position
        }
    });
```

I was helped by Vasily Kabunov 's answer in

[ScrollView .scrollTo not working? Saving ScrollView position on rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263259/scrollview-scrollto-not-working-saving-scrollview-position-on-rotation)

Comment: If the above solution does not work, just add a PostDelayed interval of 50-100 millis, as Android might need some time to redraw your view

Answer (score 1):

When you do some changes to a ScrollView, it takes a while for it to replicate the layout changes to the display list and notify the ScrollView that it is, indeed, allowed to scroll to a position.

I've managed to get it working by extending `ScrollView` with a ScrollView of my own, and adding a method that adds the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` (as suggested by MH) as needed and scrolls there later. It's a bit more automated than applying it to every case you need it (but then you need to use the new `ScrollView`). Anyway, this is the relevant code:

```
public class ZScrollView extends ScrollView {

    // Properties
    private int desiredScrollX = -1;
    private int desiredScrollY = -1;
    private OnGlobalLayoutListener gol;

    // ================================================================================================================
    // CONSTRUCTOR ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public ZScrollView(Context __context) {
        super(__context);
    }

    public ZScrollView(Context __context, AttributeSet __attrs) {
        super(__context, __attrs);
    }

    public ZScrollView(Context __context, AttributeSet __attrs, int __defStyle) {
        super(__context, __attrs, __defStyle);
    }

    // ================================================================================================================
    // PUBLIC INTERFACE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void scrollToWithGuarantees(int __x, int __y) {
        // REALLY Scrolls to a position
        // When adding items to a scrollView, you can't immediately scroll to it - it takes a while
        // for the new addition to cycle back and update the scrollView's max scroll... so we have
        // to wait and re-set as necessary

        scrollTo(__x, __y);

        desiredScrollX = -1;
        desiredScrollY = -1;

        if (getScrollX() != __x || getScrollY() != __y) {
            // Didn't scroll properly: will create an event to try scrolling again later

            if (getScrollX() != __x) desiredScrollX = __x;
            if (getScrollY() != __y) desiredScrollY = __y;

            if (gol == null) {
                gol = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int nx = desiredScrollX == -1 ? getScrollX() : desiredScrollX;
                        int ny = desiredScrollY == -1 ? getScrollY() : desiredScrollY;
                        desiredScrollX = -1;
                        desiredScrollY = -1;
                        scrollTo(nx, ny);
                    }
                };

                getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(gol);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Very useful for me since I wanted to scroll to a given View inside a ScrollView right after having added it.

Comment: Not knowing why but this trick with OnGlobalLayoutListener does not work. (at least on nexus 7 with android 5)

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault :/ I had a linear layout with LayoutTransition set. On an item added, layout animation started. And until it ended, I was not able to scroll to the postition I wanted, only to the current (during the animation) layout width.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this it works: (kotlin)**
>
> ```
>              myScrollView.post(Runnable {
>                  myScrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollValue)
>              })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to scroll recycleView:

```
private int scrollPosition = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
    ...
    // set scrollPosition value
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            scrollPosition += dy;
        }
    });
    ...
}      

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    // scrollToPosition recycleView
    recyclerView.post(() -> {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);//0 is x position
    });
}


// Save the scroll position when the activity is paused (e.g., when navigating away)
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scrollPosition = getCurrentScrollPosition();
}

private int getCurrentScrollPosition() {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    if (layoutManager != null) {
        return layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }
    return 0;
}
```