# How to scroll to specific view element inside ScrollView by knowing element id

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

my layout is inside a `ScrollView`. The id of the element and type of element to which i want to scroll with my search i found code below to do it but i'm not successful in scrolling to the element specific to the id, I have given 0,id as two parameters.

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
  scrollview.scrollTo(0,id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the ViewTreeObserver of the ScrollView and add an OnGlobalLayoutListener to the ViewTreeObserver. Then call the ScrollView.scrollTo(x,y) method from the onGlobalLayout() method of the OnGlobalLayoutListener.

```
 ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.average_scroll_mainScroll);

 ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
 vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
           mainScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
 });
```

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884572/scrollview-scrollto-doesnt-work) Courtesy - fahmy :)

However the catch here is that it takes position of the view to scroll to instead of its ID.
So you will have to find your views position first and then pass them as parameter to scrollTo. Use the below for getting the position,

```
View.getLocationOnScreen(int[] location);
```

this returns an integer array where (x = location[0] and y = location[1]). Here are [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29) for this method.

Comment: k.what should i pass as params to scrollTo directly element id will work?

Comment: See my edits now and try this one. Let me know how it goes. Also, I found this method getGlobalVisibleRect() here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout. Try this in case the first one doesn't suit your need.

Comment: but i'm just having id,type of element only with me with these only can't i scroll

Comment: Yes you can, only thing is you have to combine both the tricks(till I or U or someone else provides the direct way :)). First get the position of your View (x and y) and then call your scrollTo method. Did you try them?

Comment: ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
       TextView gotoTv = (TextView) findViewById(id);
                int x = (int) gotoTv.getX();
                int y = (int) gotoTv.getY();
               sv.scrollTo(x, y);
               this is how i'm trying and it's not working

Comment: Please post your gotoTv method.

Comment: gotoTv is textview only that i have mentioned in my earlier comment